# How would you go about removing whitespace from a string without the use of methods such as .trim or .replace?

Tags: c#, whitespace

I'm also not allowed to use lists.

My initial thought process for this was to take the initial string then to turn that into a char array. Then after copy everything that is not a space to a second char array. Then convert that char array back to a string.

So quickly it would look something like this;

```
char[] firstArray;
char[] secondArray;
string someString;

for (int i = 0; i < someString.Length; i++)
{
    firstArray = someString.ToCharArray();
    secondArray = new char[someString.Length];

    for (int j = 0; j < firstArray.Length; j++)
    {
        if (firstArray[j] != ' ') 
        {
            secondArray[j] = firstArray[j];
        }
    }

    someString = secondArray.ToString();
}
```

But when I initialise the second char array it would contain an extra char with no value if there was a space in it initially, since it was initialised to the same size as the first char array. Would I have to do a similar loop before just to count the amount of non-spaces then initialise secondArray based off that or is there a much simpler way than all of this that I am missing? (Without the use of .trim, .replace(or anything like them) or lists)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why  _without methods such as .trim or .replace_ ?

Comment: Hint: your `char[]`s are the same size, but if you want to remove something from one, the result will have to be a smaller size.

Comment: No need to convert source string to an array. And you could lose the 2nd array and use [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead.

Comment: When it's homework, be clear about that.

Comment: Your code creates a firstArray and a secondArray  for each char in someString, does that sound good?

Comment: What qualifies as a list? `A[]`, `List<A>`, and `IEnumerable<A>` are all interconvertible (and this list is not exhaustive).

Answer (score 0):

A `String` already implements `IEnumerable<char>`, so no need to turn it into an array to begin with. You can enumerate it directly and remove whitespace chars. E.g:

```
string x = "  Hello, world";
string trimmed = new String(x.Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray());
```

Comment: It looks like homework and this probably doesn't meet the limitations. "without ... or lists"

Answer (score -1):

Your code re-creates the `firstArray` array every time. And I'm not sure what the inner loop is for. Your code fixed:

```
char[] firstArray;
char[] secondArray;
string someString = "Blah blah blah";

firstArray = someString.ToCharArray();
secondArray = new char[someString.Length];

int newLength = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.Length; i++) {
    if (firstArray[i] != ' ') {
        secondArray[newLength++] = firstArray[i];
    }
}

someString = new string(secondArray, 0, newLength);
```

Another way using StringBuilder:

```
string someString = "Blah blah blah";
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

foreach(char c in someString) {
    if (!Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)) {
        sb.Append(c);
    }
}
someString = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it is correct and works within the OP's given limitations.